# Как выдрать содержимое ссылки?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Ссылка такого вида:

```
http://some.com/some?b=20130218082149&a=20130218092249&speed=1152&hash=079caaaae2fcd602c6d8dx
```

Подскажите регулярку, чтобы выдрать ее из всего хтмля + по возможности напишите ремарку по регуляркам, которые вы использовали.

Comment: лучше привести содержимое страницы. А так гадать - мало как там оно представлено. Но скорее всего что то вида

http:\/\/[^"]+

(если ссылки завершаются двойной кавычкой)

Comment: Яндекс: нашёлся 1 млн ответов...
Ну и перавя же ссылка, [тык мышой](http://phpclub.ru/talk/threads/regexp-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-url-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0.25478/) От себя могу добавить, что всё зависит от конкретных данных, универсального решения нет. Тем более на регекспах, DOM даёт более осмысленные результаты.

Answer (score 2):

Допустим исходный код такой:

```
<?php
$text = '<a href="http://some.com/some?b=20130218082149&a=20130218092249&speed=1152&hash=079caaaae2fcd602c6d8dx"></a><b></b>
<a class="123" href="http://some.com/some?b=20130218082149&a=20130218092249&speed=1152&hash=079caaaae2fcd602c6d8dx"></a><div></div>
<A href=\'http://some.com/some?b=20130218082149&a=20130218092249&speed=1152&hash=079caaaae2fcd602c6d8dx\' target="_blank"></A>
<a onclick="return false;" href="http://some.com/some?b=20130218082149&a=20130218092249&speed=1152&hash=079caaaae2fcd602c6d8dx" target="_blank" title=\'123\' ></a>';

if (preg_match_all('/<a[\S\s]*?href=[\'\"](?<url>[^\'\"]+)[\'\"][\S\s]*?>/i',$text,$matches)) {
    print_r($matches['url']);
}
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://some.com/some?b=20130218082149&a=20130218092249&speed=1152&hash=079caaaae2fcd602c6d8dx
    [1] => http://some.com/some?b=20130218082149&a=20130218092249&speed=1152&hash=079caaaae2fcd602c6d8dx
    [2] => http://some.com/some?b=20130218082149&a=20130218092249&speed=1152&hash=079caaaae2fcd602c6d8dx
    [3] => http://some.com/some?b=20130218082149&a=20130218092249&speed=1152&hash=079caaaae2fcd602c6d8dx
)
```

Видно, что прожевало все ссылки. На практике все пишут сайты как хотят и решения вроде [PHPQuery](https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/) не годятся. Редко встретишь валидный сайт. Если вы пишите парсер рука набивается очень быстро.

Разбор регулярки:

```
/<a[\S\s]*?href=[\'\"](?<url>[^\'\"]+)[\'\"][\S\s]*?>/i
```

1. Собственно выделяется фрагмент со ссылкой без закрывающего тега , ведь нам нужен только href
2. [\S\s]*? нужно, чтобы нежадно прожевать любые параметры включая переносы строк. + и *? отличается жадностью. Второй вариант не жадный - как раз то, что нужно.
3. Далее href. Кавычка может быть любой. [\'\"] - означает любой из символ в скобках.
4. Далее выделяем сам url. (?[^\'\"]+). Мы берем все символы не равные кавычкам(^ в начале множества).
5. Далее опять проглатываем ненужное и закрываем открывающий тег.

В итоге preg_match_all разместит все урлы в массив $matches['url']. Если использовать preg_match, то найдет только одно вхождение. Флаг i в конце выражения даст регистронезависимость.

Есть хороший сайт с [конструктором](http://www.pcre.ru/eval/) и [документацией](http://www.pcre.ru/docs/javascript/) по выражениям. Яваскрипт или пхп - принципиальной разницы нет, т.к. используется одна и та же библиотека.

Тренируйтесь и изучайте регулярные выражения, они очень полезны и функциональны. Удачи!